# Move chapters titles to specific position on the page

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I will like to move all the chapter titles (here Aim) to be lower than the black box with the chapter number inside it. See the below figure for an visulalization of the problem.

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt,oldfontcommands,standalone]{memoir} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\chaptercolor}{black}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {\node[fill=\chaptercolor,
        font=\sffamily\fontsize{50}{40}\bf\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=3cm] 
        at (7,0) 
        (numb) {\thechapter};
        \node[rotate=90,
        anchor=south,
        inner sep=0pt,
        font=\Huge\sffamily]
        at (numb.west) {\SPREAD\chaptertitlename};
}}
{20pt}
{\Huge\bfseries\color{\chaptercolor}#1}%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\SPREAD}{m}
{% full expand the argument
    \vincent_spread:f { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \vincent_spread:n #1
{% with \tl_map_inline:nn we insert \hfil between letters; a final \unskip kills the last \hfil
    \makebox[3cm][s]{\tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \hfil } \unskip}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vincent_spread:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Aim}
    \vspace*{2cm}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your titleformat command to

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=(numb.base)]
    {\node[fill=\chaptercolor,
        font=\sffamily\fontsize{50}{40}\bf\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=3cm] 
        at (7,0) 
        (numb) {\thechapter};
        \node[rotate=90,
        anchor=south,
        inner sep=0pt,
        font=\Huge\sffamily]
        at (numb.west) {\SPREAD\chaptertitlename};
}}
{0pt} %<- increase
{\Huge\bfseries\color{\chaptercolor}#1}%
```

If you (really) want to move "Aim" further down, you may increase `0pt` in the next-to-last line to a larger value. And if you want to keep the distance to the test the same, use

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=(numb.base)]
    {\node[fill=\chaptercolor,
        font=\sffamily\fontsize{50}{40}\bf\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=3cm] 
        at (7,0) 
        (numb) {\thechapter};
        \node[rotate=90,
        anchor=south,
        inner sep=0pt,
        font=\Huge\sffamily]
        at (numb.west) {\SPREAD\chaptertitlename};
}}
{1cm} %<- increase
{\Huge\bfseries\color{\chaptercolor}#1\vspace*{-1cm}}% <- add neg vspace
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, increasing the suggested number will also move the text exactly the samme distance down the page :(

Comment: @JesperH I misinterpreted the task, and posted an update.